# How to add Yes-No buttons to a jQuery UI dialog control?On click of Yes button the form should submit & on click of No button the dialog should close

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

jQuery, etc. for my website. Now I'm showing the HTML of one file into a jQuery-UI dialog modal pop-up. This HTML contains a form with Submit button(value="Yes") and a normal button(value="No"). But what I want is instead of keeping these buttons as a part of HTML I'm showing into a dialog, I want to assign these buttons to the dialog as a parameter when I'm displaying the jQuQery dialog pop-up. But the functionality of both of these buttons should be same. That is, on click of Yes button the form should get submit, the modal dialog should get close and on click of No button the modal dialog should close.In short, I want to remove these buttons from HTML and asssign to dialog modal directly. For your reference I'm putting below the HTML code as well as the dialog pop-up code.

```
<div id="favouriteQuestion" class="c-popup" style="display:none;">
  <div class="error_msg" id="report_error" style="text-align:center; margin-top:5px;">
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>  
  <form name="add_favourite_question_form" id="add_favourite_question_form" class="login_box" method="post" action="{$site_url}favourite_question.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_submitted" id="form_submitted" value="yes"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="op" id="op" value="add"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="fav_que_id" id="fav_que_id"/>
    <table class="trnsction_details" width="100%" cellpadding="5">
      <tbody>    
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p>Do you want to add this question as your favourite question?</p>
          </td>
          <td></td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" name="yes" value="Yes" class="add_fav_que_yes" class="buttonin"/>
            <input type="button" name="no" value="No" class="add_fav_que_no" class="buttonin" onclick="$('#favouriteQuestion').dialog('close')";/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>  
</div>

<a href ="#" style="margin-left:300px;" class="fav_que" id="{$question_data.question_id}">Add To Favourite Question</a>
```

The jQuery code for it is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


  $("#favouriteQuestion").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal:true,
    title: "Add To Favourite Question List",
    width: 400,                     
    close:{
    }           
    });
$(document).on("click","a.fav_que", function (e) {
  var que_id = this.id;  

  $("#fav_que_id").val(que_id);
  $("#favouriteQuestion").dialog('open');

  return false;
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: now you have added modal box jQuery code above,then what is problem?

Comment: @PratikJoshi:I don't want to keep the Yes & No buttons as part of HTML of a form(i.e. the content in a div). I want to assign these buttons separately using buttons attribute of a jQuery UI dialog. But the functionality should be same.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method ,It uses yes no button ,on no form dialog closes,And on yes you can apply logic of form Submit here =>   // Do Form submit logic in code

```
function yesnodialog(button1, button2, element){
  var btns = {};
  btns[button1] = function(){ 
      element.parents('li').hide();
      $(this).dialog("close");
  };
  btns[button2] = function(){ 
      // Do Form submit logic
      $(this).dialog("close");
  };
  $("<div></div>").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    title: 'Condition',
    modal:true,
    buttons:btns
  });
}
$('.delete').click(function(){
    yesnodialog('Yes', 'No', $(this));
})
```

With live -

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/CdwB9/4/

$('.delete').live('click', function(){
    yesnodialog('Yes', 'No', $(this));
})